# How to set springframework @Transactional with AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to use `spring-aspects` to make my methods transactional, but without using Spring AOP (Spring AOP works just fine with: `<tx:annotation-driven/>`).
I'm using Maven to manage my project.

Is there a way to do **compile time** weaving on my project classes so "they are `Transactional`".
I was trying to use the [Mojo's AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/), but without any good results.

Please help.

Comment: What's the problem with the aspectj plugin? Can you should your pom?

Comment: No problem with plugin I had problem with spring configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. 
Maven plugin works fine but the problem was with my spring config:
I had:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

What I needed was:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Now it works fine. And performace of my @Transactional methods improved and that what I was aming for.

Here is my maven aspectj plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
       </aspectLibraries>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have a question for you: in this post you have replaced the type of the `transactionManager` bean from `JpaTransactionManager` to `HibernateTransactionManager`. So you are saying `org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect` is not working with JPA?

Comment: I don't think so. Most probably I messed something up/didn't set it up properly for JPA to work, but somehow it worked for Hibernate. It was a long time ago, I don't even remember what project it was.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you can try this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the answer I gave on how to do the same in java config:

[Spring @Transactional is applied both as a dynamic Jdk proxy and an aspectj aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573188/spring-transactional-is-applied-both-as-a-dynamic-jdk-proxy-and-an-aspectj-aspe/33937697#33937697)

Hope it helps